# Minecraft disappearing after installation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows

I have bought Minecraft from the Windows Store on my PC, it says "You own this product" and when I click Install (which is in blue) it installs and then disappears. If I go back onto the store it tells me to install it again.

I have repeated this process multiple times and I am still not able to play. What is happening?

Comment: Is this Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition or just regular Minecraft?

Comment: What operating system do you use (Windows, or Mac, or ...)?

Comment: Have you checked to ensure you have enough free space on your HDD to install Minecraft?

Answer (score 2):

Search for:

> %appdata%

This will not appear unless you type (or paste) the whole thing in. If you have Minecraft installed, you should be able to find a file around there named:

> .minecraft

There is a dot!

If you don't see that you either (somehow) specified other saving folder (unlikely) or some weird bug occured contact Minecraft support (https://help.mojang.com/).

If you see the .minecraft file but you can't play the game go to programs ("program files" on some devices) and try to search for Minecraft there.

NOTICE:
I use Windows 10 it may not work on any other system (as far as my memory goes it worked on Windows 8 too).

You may also need to ensure you have enough available hard drive space to install this item or it will not install, quitting out automatically.

To check, look at the storage requirements on the store page. Then right-click on your My Computer icon, select properties and if "available space" is less than what Minecraft requires, you need to make space on the HDD before trying again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not referring to the Windows Phone, I would recommend you to **only** purchase the PC (Java) or Windows 10 Edition versions from Minecraft's official website: https://minecraft.net/

Purchasing off the Windows store, since it has had fake apps before, can be unreliable.

**Scary, but serious, Warning:** Using *any* wireless access point, especially at ones like coffee shops, that multiple people connect to, your payment information has a chance to be stolen by any of the other connected devices. You can even have web pages and other internet data you recieve be injected with malicious code!

Answer (score -3):

Try searching for Minecraft on your computer. The search bar will be in the Windows start menu.